# Using Formulas in GoogleSheets for multiple cells

Tags: if-statement

If I have the title "Comm" in Cell A, then I want Cell C1 to be whatever Date Cell B has + 14 days. 
If I have "Recruit" in Cell A, then I want Cell C1 to be whatever Date Cell B has + 30 days.

pasted in cell C1
=if(A1="Comm","B1+14,"")")

The result was False    - what I need is a date +14 days from Cell B's entry.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

(Example)
If Cell B9 says H2O Recruit or PMS recruit then f9 will be 30 days from E9 otherwise make it 14 days from E9

(Answer)
=IF(OR(B9="H2O Recruit",B9="PMS Recruit"), E9+30,E9+14)